# $.ajax() variable scoping issues

Tags: jquery

I have a scoping issue I am not able to figure out.

Please see this code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var jq = $.ajax({

            });

    jq.done(function(data){

    })
},1000);

// How to access jq object here?
```

How can I access jq outside setTimeout? Here's a live sample http://jsfiddle.net/g54Cx/

Comment: Scope the variable outside the timeout. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work. Also what about the "global variable is bad" advise

Comment: If the question is _how can I access jq_ then it absolutely does work. However, the VALUE of `jq` is probably not what you think it is. Show us what you're trying to do; you've got an XY problem here.

Comment: Also there is no reason why the outer scope of the `setTimeout` needs to be the global scope, so...

Comment: putting variables in the outterscope is bad because of collisions.  In other words, if everyone put their variables on the window, what happens if two people use the same variable name?  Say you are using a few libraries in your code and someone else uses the variable jq.  Now either your code, theirs or both, will break.

Comment: To access the variable outside the setTimeout you need to declare it outside the setTimeout, but remember that it will not have a value until the function is executed.
http://jsfiddle.net/g54Cx/1/

Comment: @Mathletics is the only person trying to help the OP, rather than answer a possibly bad question.

Comment: In this case, jq called after settimeOut does not contain the deferred/promises methods. So for eg:, you cannot to jq.always after setTimeout

Comment: @Thomasmkov of course it doesn't. the setTimeout hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `var jq;` out of Timeout definition, like this:

```
var jq;

setTimeout(function () {
      jq = $.ajax({

      });

      jq.done(function(data){

      })
}, 1000);

console.log(jq);
```

Comment: In this case, jq called after settimeOut does not contain the methods like jq.always() cannot be called after setTimeout

Comment: Yes, of course. It will be available only after 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the other suggestions...

You can pass it to another function:
http://jsfiddle.net/7aZdm/

```
myFunction(jq) {
  //access in here
}

setTimeout(function () {
    var jq = $.ajax({
                url: "/echo/json/",
                type: "POST",
                data: {json: '{"message": "Hello"}'},
                dataType: "json"
            });
    myFunction(jq);
    jq.done(function(data){
        $("#msg").text("Response is = " + data.message);
    })
},1000);
```

or just assign it to the window object, but that's generally bad practice

```
window.jq = jq
```